# How to make the number of range working in generator

Tags: python, html, django

How to make this range working in function. Whenever I limit `n`, it gives every result without limit.

```
# This is to show you
def generator(f, n, *args, **kwargs):
    return (f(*args, **kwargs) for __ in range(n))

# This is the problem
target1 = Destination.objects.all()
for field in target1:
    [Destination(img = f'{field.img}',title = f'{field.title}') for __ in range(2)]
```

Comment: Will anybody answer my specific question?

Comment: Your edit is really confusing. You are not calling `generator` and you now have some `Destination` object which isn't defined anywhere. Maybe this should be a new question once you clarified everything.

Comment: This Destination function is in models.py which has title and image.

Comment: My point here is whenever I call ```field.img``` and ```field.title``` it is showing me all the results. I want to make a range of it.

Comment: Will anybody answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is make a generator. Generators work by yeilding each result they generate. Their state is saved until each time you call them, so it picks up after the last call to `yeild`. For more info on generators, read [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

This is what your code would look like implementing this:

```py
def generator(f, n, *args, **kwargs):
    for __ in range(n):
        yield f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hey Calder I used it but it is giving me error ```'generator' object has no attribute 'get'```

Comment: How are you using it? Generators are usually used in a for loop or with next()

Answer (score 2):

You can just change the `[]` into `()` to turn it from a list comprehension into a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
def generator(f, n, *args, **kwargs):
    return (f(*args, **kwargs) for __ in range(n))
```

For example:

```
def f(b, a):
    return a+b

def generator(f, n, *args, **kwargs):
    return (f(*args, **kwargs) for __ in range(n))

g = generator(f, 5, "bar", a="foo")

list(g)

# ['foobar', 'foobar', 'foobar', 'foobar', 'foobar']
```